# No main.storyboard or ViewController.swift upon initialization of new project in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I just got Xcode and I am trying to follow an online tutorial but in every single tutorial, when a new project is made (a single activity) app, the project comes with 2 files that I simply don't have by default! I can't figure out how to make a main.storyboard or ViewController.swift file by default upon creating a project.

The only files I have are AppDelegate.swift, SceneDelegate.swift, and ContentView.swift. I also have Assets.xcassets, LaunchScreen.storyboard, Info.plist, Preview Content directory, and Products directory.

Is this part of a new update or something? Or is there some way I can get those 2 files to create upon initialization?

I tried reinstalling, and have made multiple new projects - each time they lack those 2 crucial files, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hmm I'll try right now!

Comment: Update: you are a genius. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the **latest Xcode**, select `Storyboard` from the **User Interface** dropdown,
[image]

**Older Xcode**

Unselect `Use SwiftUI` at the following step,

[image]

Comment: Is there any benefit to using SwiftUI?

Comment: @ian-campbell `SwiftUI` is the latest framework to build `UI` so it'll be the way forward to create apps. Major benefit of this framework to me is the reactive way of doing things.

Comment: but then how to access the view controller

Comment: there is no view controller in swiftui.

Comment: In Xcode 13, there is no option for Storyboard, and there is no checkbox Swift UI, So my new project is always using SwiftUI now.

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry Storyboards can not go away at this point. You need to tap that `User Interface` to see the options.

Answer (score 12):

On latest Xcode release you should change in the dropdown menu from "Swift UI" to "Storyboard"